# XSLT - check if tag has a specific element

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a problem with converting XML file using XSLT. This is how my XML look like (part of it):

```
 <articles>
...
    <art Name="Product name" BrandName="Brand Name">
    <groups>
       <group ArticleGroupId="64" Default="0"/>
       <group ArticleGroupId="1259" Default="1"/>
       <group ArticleGroupId="1401" Default="0"/>
    </groups>
    </art>
...
    <art Name="Product name" BrandName="Brand Name">
    <groups>
       <group ArticleGroupId="64" Default="0"/>
       <group ArticleGroupId="1401" Default="0"/>
    </groups>
    </art>
...
</articles>
```

I want to create file with products that contains ArticleGroupID 1259.

I tried with this code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="articles/art">
                                
    <xsl:if test="(
    @ArticleGroupId = '1259')"> 
                                        
                <product>
                    <producer>
                        <xsl:attribute name="name">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@BrandName">
                        </xsl:value-of>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </producer>
                    <description>
                        <name><xsl:value-of select="@Name"></xsl:value-of></name>
                    </description>
                </product>

     </xsl:if> 
</xsl:for-each>
```

But it just don't work. I know my xsl:if is wrong, but i don't know how to deal with it. Please, help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `test="@ArticleGroupId = '1259'"` is looking for an `ArticleGroupId` attribute of the `art` element, and it doesn't have one.

You want `test="groups/group/@ArticleGroupId = '1259'`.

This takes advantage of the fact that in an XPath comparison X = Y where X is a node-set and Y is a literal value, the result will be true if any node in X compares equal to Y.

Incidentally, you can simplify this:

```
            <producer>
                <xsl:attribute name="name">
                <xsl:value-of select="@BrandName">
                </xsl:value-of>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </producer>
```

to

```
            <producer name="{@BrandName}"/>
```